# How to disable Preview from opening up the last couple items viewed? osx lion

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

When I download a PDF and open it in Preview on OS X Lion, Preview opens the last couple documents that I viewed. It seems to arbitrarily open anywhere from the last document to the last x documents.

Does anyone know how to disable this feature?

Comment: A similar and detailed answer is at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32429/lions-preview-regularly-hangs-when-unhiding-with-open-documents/32872#32872

Comment: Nice i have the same question too. Opened last page is good feature, but opened last document is annoying.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To stop *only* Preview from doing this open up Terminal.app and enter:

```
defaults write com.apple.Preview NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false
```

To re-enable this at any time enter:

```
defaults write com.apple.Preview NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool true
```

If you want to turn off the resume-on-load feature for *all* applications you can go to System Preferences -> General and at the bottom of the screen uncheck the option `Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps` to prevent any application from doing this.

[image: Turn off application restore features for all applications]